# Javascript Regex - Remove single spaces NOT double spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove singles spaces from a string but *not* double spaces.

Using regex I've tried this, however it is invalid and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
\s+{1,1}
```

This is what I want to achieve:

**Raw string:**

```
"Okay,  let ’s  get  star ted,  Bret t "
```

**After regex replace** (keeping the double spacing):

```
"Okay,  let’s  get  started,  Brett"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, I believe you <s>have to</s> can resort to a callback function:

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, function(m) {
    return m.length === 1 ? '' : m;
});
```

Comment: +1 for callback solution, i think you missed the `g` modifier :)

Comment: Indeed I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
"Okay,  let ’s  get  star ted,  Bret t ".replace(/(\S)\s(\S)/g, '$1$2')
```

But this will not remove the space at the end of string, you could trim it by:

```
"Okay,  let ’s  get  star ted,  Bret t ".replace(/(\S)\s(\S)|\s$/g, '$1$2')
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that :D

Comment: Alternately, check that a space is either the first character, or preceded by a non-whitespace, and isn't followed by a space. `" Okay,  let ’s  get  star ted,  Bret t ".replace(/(^|\S)\s(?!\s)/g,'$1');`

Answer (score 1):

Based on expression greediness this is a viable solution:

```
"Okay,  let ’s  get  star ted,  Bret t ".replace(/(\s{2,})|\s/g, '$1')
```

It matches two or more spaces if possible, for which the replacement is `$1`, effectively falling back to replacing a single space with nothing.

Comment: That's cool too. You don't even need the second capture group. `\s{2}` might have to be changed to `\s{2,}` if the OP truly wants to replace single spaces only.

Answer (score 0):

```
/([^\s]\s{1}[^\s])|\s$/g
```

will solve your problem

`\s` is for one space

`^\s` is for NOT space

`{1}` is a quatifier which tells the number to be one

http://regex101.com/r/uO3iJ4

Comment: `[^\s]` is also `\S`, and with that replacement it's basically the first version of xdazz's answer.

Comment: ohh i thought this is just one way of saying it. People are there who dont know everything.

Comment: What I meant to say is that this has the problem of not removing space from the end of a string :)